# ffmpeg in python - extracting meta data

Tags: python, performance, video, ffmpeg, metadata

I use ffmpeg for Python to extract meta data from video files. I think the official documentation is available here: https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/

To extract meta data (duration, resolution, frames per second, etc.) I use the function "ffmpeg.probe" as provided. Sadly, when running it on a large amount of video files, it is rather inefficient as it seems to (obviously?) load the whole file into memory each time to read just a small amount of data.

If this is not what it does, maybe someone could explain what the cause might be for the rather extensive runtime.

Otherwise, is there any way to retrieve meta data in a more efficient way using ffmpeg or some other library?

Any feedback or help is very much appreciated.

Edit: For clarity I added my code here:

```
pool = mp.Pool()
videos = []
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    pool.apply_async(ffmpeg.probe, args=[os.path.join(directory, file)], callback=videos.append)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The imports and the definition of the paths are missing, but it should suffice to understand what is going on.

Comment: Can you please post your code? There is a chance that your implementation is not efficient.

Comment: I just added some code for clarity.

Comment: Code "for clarity" is not enough. **Next time you post a question:** We like to see an executable code sample (starting with `import` statements...). It doesn't mean you should post your entire project. The site guideline is posting a minimal reproducible code sample. That means making an effort, and make changes to your code so it be minimal and reproducible (and executable)...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's the first question I posted and I didn't take the time to read all of the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) directly. Unfortunately ffmpeg can be CPU expensive sometimes but it all depends on your hardware specs.

Answer (score 0):

> running it on a large amount of video files

This is where multithreading/multiprocessing could potentially be helpful IF the slowdown comes from subprocess spawning (and not from actual I/O). This may not help as file I/O in general takes time compared to virtually everything else.

> load the whole file into memory each time to read just a small amount of data

This is incorrect assertion IMO. It should only read relevant headers/packets to retrieve the metadata. You are likely paying subprocess tax more than anything else.

> a way to retrieve meta data

(1) Adding to what @Peter Hassaballeh said above, ffprobe has options to limit what to look up. If you only need to get the container(format)-level info or only of a particular stream, you can specify exactly what you need (to an extent). This could save some time.

(2) You can try MediaInfo (another free tool like ffprobe) which you should be able to call from Python as well.

(3) If you are dealing with a particular file format, the fastest way is to decode it yourself in Pyton, read only the bytes that matters to you. Depending on what is the current bottleneck, it may not be that drastic of an improvement, tho.

Comment: As you might now see after adding my code, I included multiprocessing which delivers a significant speedup of around 5x.

Thanks for confirming that ffprobe actually only reads the relevant file headers to retrieve the metadata.

The file format is mp4 and doing it manually is certainly a possibility, but I think it would not be worth to invest the time considering the limited expected speedup.